# PHP MySQL Select data between where a row has specific data to where a row has specific data

Tags: php, mysql

This is a little hard to explain, but I would like to obtain data from a table between a range of rows where the row has a specific entry start point and end point.

```
234 ****************************************************
235 some data
236 more data
237 even more data
238 etc...
239 ****************************************************
```

So between the *'s is the data I am interested in.
The issue is that this will vary, so the row number will be different every time. And it may appear more than once in the table, which is ok to pull every entry. Actually its necessary.

Let me know if you need any more info...

Comment: Can you explain more what you want to do when the delimiter row occurs more than once? IE, you want everything from the first one to the last one? or you want all the rows between each delimeter row as one result?

Comment: There's an "id" int, "info" varchar. So the ID is really just representative of a "line number", the info column contains the data to pull. The data to pull is between the *'s and this will vary pretty much every time. So I want all the data from the first set of *'s to the second set of *'s. Then if that occurs more than once in the table to repeat the result. Its also ok to pull the *'s if required. Each row should be pulled.

Comment: I think I understand, posting an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it just in SQL, here's how I did it in PHP using two queries and some PHP logic to build the second query.

```
//this array is to simulate your table, don't make it.
$data = [1 => '*****', 'This', 'is', 'data', '*****', '*****', 'more', 'data', '*****', 'random', '*****', 'rows', '*****'];

//Run a query to get all the ids
$sql = "SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE data =  '*****' ORDER BY id ASC";
//assign them to an array - I did it manually.
$ids = [1, 5, 6, 9, 11, 13];

//Build the query to get the end sets.
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ";
while (count($ids)) {
    $start = array_shift($ids);
    $end = array_shift($ids);
    $query .= "(id >= $start AND id <= $end) OR ";
}
$query = trim($query, " OR ");
echo $query;
```

Comment: that was perfect (after a little fiddling). Did exactly what I was after. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The value you are interested in is stored in one table column (cell)? If so, which data type it is? If it is text data, you can use MATCH or REGEXP function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp .

But notice that it will be very slow.

Comment: the code above is quite representative of the table. The number is the id column. The *'s etc is the 'info' column. The data I am after is in the 'info' column